# File modes are not working in turbo c++

Tags: c++, binaryfiles, turbo-c++

I tried using file modes like ios::app and ios::ate are not working.
Each time I write to a binary file the contents are getting replaced with the new contents. I even tried using seekp(ios::end)  instead of append mode and it still doesn't add contents instead only replaces it.
This is the code I typed :

```
#include<fstream.h>
 //included other required header files
   struct test 
   {char que[100];
   char ans[20];
    };

  int main()
{
test s ;
ofstream out("test.dat",ios::binary||ios::app);
strcpy(s.que,"abcd");
strcpy(s.ans,"agg");
out.write((char*)&s,sizeof(s));
return 0;
}
```

I don't realize what is wrong. I was wondering if it was because turbo c++ is an old compiler ? If so how do I append contents to the end of the file ?

Comment: *I was wondering if it was because turbo c++ is an old compiler*  Yes, get a modern C++ compiler.

Comment: Our school requires us to use turboc++ only. So can't do anything about that.

Comment: Then you are not learning proper C++, as it stands today (or has stood for 17 years ago).  For example `<fstream.h>` won't exist if you attempted to use a modern C++ compiler as it is non-standard (for example, the Visual Studio compilers removed this header starting with Visual Studio 2003).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace this:

```
ios::binary||ios::app
```

With this:

```
ios::binary | ios::app
```

Operations that are to be combined are tied together using `|` (bitwise `or`), not `||` (logical `or`).